# Why are the planets plotting separately?

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to create a solar system simulation and want the planets to move at different speeds but when I attempt this the planets plot individually and cause a glitch. (my code contains all the planets)
how could I make this run smoother?

```
close all 

%Set broadly used variables
t =-pi:0.01:pi;
y0 = 0;
d = linspace(0,2*pi,629);

%Data for planets
%Mercury
x0_mu = 1.17;
a_mu = 3;
b_mu = 2.95;
x_mu = x0_mu+a_mu*cos(t);
y_mu = y0+b_mu*sin(t);
%Venus 
x0_v = 0.0689;
a_v = 5;
b_v = 4.97;
x_v = x0_v+a_v*cos(t);
y_v = y0+b_v*sin(t);
%Creating animation
for k=1:length(d)
    clf
    dk = d(k);
%Sun
    plot(0,0,'yo','LineWidth', 1, 'Markersize', 20, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]) 
    hold on 
    for k=1:length(d)
%Mercury  
    xmuk = x_mu(k);
    ymuk = y_mu(k);
    plot(xmuk,ymuk,'ro', 'Markersize', 4, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.8500 0.3250 0.0980]);
    hold on
    plot(x_mu,y_mu, 'k');
    hold on
    pause(0.01)
    end
     for k=1:length(d) 
%Venus    
    xvk = x_v(k);
    yvk = y_v(k);
    plot(xvk,yvk,'yo', 'Markersize', 7, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]);
    hold on
    plot(x_v,y_v, 'k');
    hold on
    pause(0.05)
     end
end
```

Comment: Why do you loop over `k` inside your loop over `k`? You might want to remove the inner loops, I think.

Comment: but when i do that they move at the same speed

Answer (score 3):

You have a loop over `k` inside a loop over `k`, which makes no sense. You need a single loop over `k`, and within it update the position of each of the planets for that time step.

Here I've modified your code to do so (I've changed some variable names as well, to make things a bit more readable):

```matlab
close all 

% Set broadly used variables
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y0 = 0;
t_e = 365.256;    % Earth period, in Earth days

% Data for planets
% Mercury
x0_mu = 1.17;
a_mu = 3;
b_mu = 2.95;
t_mu = 87.9691;   % period, in Earth days
x_mu = x0_mu + a_mu * cos(phi);
y_mu = y0 + b_mu * sin(phi);
sz_mu = 4;
% Venus
x0_v = 0.0689;
a_v = 5;
b_v = 4.97;
t_v = 224.701;
x_v = x0_v + a_v * cos(phi);
y_v = y0 + b_v * sin(phi);
sz_v = 7;
% Creating animation
for t = 1:t_e % simulate one earth year (t is in Earth days)
    clf
    hold on
    % Sun
    plot(0,0,'yo','LineWidth', 1, 'Markersize', 20, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]) 
    % Mercury
    xmuk = interp1(phi, x_mu, mod(t / t_mu, 1) * 2 * pi);
    ymuk = interp1(phi, y_mu, mod(t / t_mu, 1) * 2 * pi);
    plot(xmuk,ymuk,'ro', 'Markersize', sz_mu, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.8500 0.3250 0.0980]);
    plot(x_mu,y_mu, 'k');
    % Venus
    xvk = interp1(phi, x_v, mod(t / t_v, 1) * 2 * pi);
    yvk = interp1(phi, y_v, mod(t / t_v, 1) * 2 * pi);
    plot(xvk,yvk,'yo', 'Markersize', sz_v, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]);
    plot(x_v,y_v, 'k');
    pause(0.05)
end
```

We're counting time in days (Earth days) in variable `t`. At each time point (once a day) we compute the position around the orbit for each of the planets, and draw the planet at that position. New variables `t_mu` and `t_v` are the periods in days for each of the planets.

However, to make the animation really smooth, it would be better to not delete the plot every iteration, but move the plotted elements instead. This is a lot simpler:

```matlab
close all 

% Set broadly used variables
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y0 = 0;
t_e = 365.256;    % Earth period, in Earth days
clf
hold on

% Sun
plot(0,0,'yo','LineWidth', 1, 'Markersize', 20, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]) 
% Mercury
x0_mu = 1.17;
a_mu = 3;
b_mu = 2.95;
t_mu = 87.9691;   % period, in Earth days
x_mu = x0_mu + a_mu * cos(phi);
y_mu = y0 + b_mu * sin(phi);
sz_mu = 4;
plot(x_mu, y_mu, 'k');
mu = plot(x_mu(1), y_mu(1), 'ro', 'Markersize', sz_mu, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.8500 0.3250 0.0980]);
% Venus
x0_v = 0.0689;
a_v = 5;
b_v = 4.97;
t_v = 224.701;
x_v = x0_v + a_v * cos(phi);
y_v = y0 + b_v * sin(phi);
sz_v = 7;
plot(x_v ,y_v, 'k');
v = plot(xvk(1), yvk(1), 'yo', 'Markersize', sz_v, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]);
% Creating animation
for t = 1:t_e % simulate one earth year (t is in Earth days)
   pause(0.05)
   % Mercury
   xmuk = interp1(phi, x_mu, mod(t / t_mu, 1) * 2 * pi);
   ymuk = interp1(phi, y_mu, mod(t / t_mu, 1) * 2 * pi);
   set(mu, 'xdata', xmuk, 'ydata', ymuk);
   % Venus
   xvk = interp1(phi, x_v, mod(t / t_v, 1) * 2 * pi);
   yvk = interp1(phi, y_v, mod(t / t_v, 1) * 2 * pi);
   set(v, 'xdata', xvk, 'ydata', yvk);
end
```

The next extension is to create an array with the information for the planets, and loop over the planets, so that you don't have variables `mu`, `v`, `e`, etc. but instead `p(1)`, `p(2)`, `p(3)`, etc. That will avoid a lot of duplicated code:

```matlab
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
y0 = 0;
t_e = 365.256;    % Earth period, in Earth days
p = [];
% Mercury
p(1).x0 = 1.17;
p(1).a = 3;
p(1).b = 2.95;
p(1).period = 87.9691;
p(1).size = 4;
p(1).color = [0.8500 0.3250 0.0980];
% Venus
p(2).x0 = 0.0689;
p(2).a = 5;
p(2).b = 4.97;
p(2).period = 224.701;
p(2).size = 7;
p(2).color = [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250];
% etc.
nplanets = numel(p);
% Plot orbits and planets
close all 
clf
hold on
plot(0,0,'yo','LineWidth', 1, 'Markersize', 20, 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.9290 0.6940 0.1250]) 
for ii=1:nplanets
   p(ii).x = p(ii).x0 + p(ii).a * cos(phi);
   p(ii).y = y0 + p(ii).b * sin(phi);
   plot(p(ii).x, p(ii).y, 'k');
   p(ii).h = plot(p(ii).x(1), p(ii).y(1), 'ro', 'Markersize', p(ii). size, 'MarkerFaceColor', p(ii).color);
end
% Animate planets
for t = 1:t_e % simulate one earth year (t is in Earth days)
   pause(0.05)
   for ii=1:nplanets
      a = mod(t / p(ii).period, 1) * 2 * pi;
      x = interp1(phi, p(ii).x, a);
      y = interp1(phi, p(ii).y, a);
      set(p(ii).h, 'xdata', x, 'ydata', y);
   end
end
```

Comment: Nice animation  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbHzX.gif

Comment: @CourtneyReid See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)